# Net has only one pin in multi-sheet design

Tags: altium

I am doing a schematic and following multi-sheet hierarchical design. Connecting two sheet entries with a bus is giving me an error of "net has only one pin". I have read many articles on this, but I want to understand what is wrong with this and even after verifying the net is connected at both the ends, why the error shows up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are only showing one end of the bus, are you also connecting it somewhere else from the bus...

Comment: If your bus is INLOGIC[0..2], you need to name the wires connected to it INLOGIC0, INLOGIC1, and INLOGIC2. If you name them all just INLOGIC, then they'll all end up connected together in the netlist, and the project compiler will get confused.

Comment: @ThePhoton Ohhh, what a silly mistake.. Thank you for pointing me there :)

Answer (score 2):

GO to menu bar, 
click on "Project->Project Options"
select "Error Reporting" tab
under items of "Violations associated with nets"
click on item "Nets with only one pin"
change "ERROR" to "Warning" or "No Report" in Report mode column

good luck!

Comment: This is just hiding the error, the connection would not work. This is the error you sometime get when your buses and harnesses are not working like you intended, and yet you didn't break any other rules, so I would not hide it.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/WorkspaceManager_Err-NetsWithOnlyOnePin((Nets+with+Only+One+Pin))_AD

Follow this link to the altium user manual. It means that one pin is connected on that particular sheet, not the entire document. Try compiling one sheet at a time and remove the error/warning where ever it exist.